# Android-3D-Carousel item click in android

Tags: android, carousel

i working with Android-3D-Carousel [code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel)

and when i click in any position in Carousel layout it work as i click in the front icon , how can i solve this click issue .
i mean that when i click in any position in carousel layout , i need it  doesnot take click action of the front image .

any one can help me .

Comment: I counter this problem too. And looking for solutions but no result here.....

Answer (score 0):

I use the carousel too and for me it work correctly I mean when i click any items of the carousel it take me a reaction. if your problem didn't solve yet please put your code in this page.